# Passing context "this" from one function into another inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm practicing ajax with forms, and.. I guess trying to confuse myself more and more for the sake of learning.

This might not make any sense, but I'm trying to log the first and last name, specifically through the conLog function. But it's showing as undefined because I think the context "this" is not there, and I'm not sure how to set it. I managed to set it inside the ajax however.

So if you open the log, the 2nd line says undefined, while in the first, the input from the first form is logged.

https://jsfiddle.net/2oLjqv7c/3/

Assuming that's the problem, how do I pass "this" into conLog?

thanks in advance! and I found a few posts with the same question, but sigh... I guess I can't grasp it unless if it's applied to my personal problem (still need to learn to read other people's codes I guess).

HTML

```
<form action="/echo/html/" id="form1" method="post">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" value="first" id="firstName">
  <br/>
  Last Name:
  <input type="text" value="last" id="lastName">
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" form="form1" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
function Display(el) {
    this.el = el;
  this.firstName = this.el.find("#firstName");
  this.lastName = this.el.find("#lastName");
  var confirmation = this;
    this.el.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax('/echo/html/', {
        success: function() {
        console.log('success' + " " + this.firstName.val());
        this.conLog(this.firstName.val(), this.lastName.val());
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('fail');
      },
      timeout: 3000,
      context: confirmation
    });
  });

  this.conLog = function(first, last) {
    this.first = this.first;
    this.last = this.last;
    console.log(this.first + " " + this.last);
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    Display($('#form1'));
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass `this`.  Because you're already passing the `first` and `last` parameters.  Just use those directly like this:

```
this.conLog = function(first, last) {
  console.log(first + " " + last);
};
```

Note I changed `this.first` and `this.last` to just `first` and `last`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for.
I modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oLjqv7c/4/) to output the name to a `<p>` element.
I just modified how the props of `consLog` are assigned:

```
  this.conLog = function(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    console.log(this.first + " " + this.last);
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = this.first + " " + this.last;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are quite a few ways to achieve this... one of the easiest is to set `var self = this;` above or around where you have `this.el = el;` and no matter how deep down your functions are you can always use this reference to it by taking advantage of Javascript's functional scope. If like you say you are learning i suggest you look into `Function.bind Function.call and Function.apply` which all relate to your question... [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is always a great place to start..